# Using same resource bundle in Java as well as JavaScript using (jquery.i18n.properties plugin)

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jakarta-ee, internationalization

I have a J2EE application where I need to implement internationalization ( I'm not using any frameworks, it's kind of a legacy application).

My Java code currently is something like this:

```
public String getString(Locale locale, String key){
    ResourceBundle bundle
            = ResourceBundle.getBundle("com.mycode.labels", locale);
    return bundle.getString(key);
}
```

As you can see the resource files are in the java class path, so that i can use the class path for the getBundle's argument.

But now, I want to use the same  resource bundle from javascript. I figured I could use the JQuery.i18n.properties plugin like this:

First we initialize it like :

```
var lang = 'en'; // which can be en_US or anything, should be dynamic
jQuery.i18n.properties({
    name:'labels', 
    path:'Bundle/', 
    mode:'map',
    language: lang
});
```

Then use a global function like ( for the example, otherwise i'd use it within my own libs, it shouldn't matter here.) :

```
function geti18nString(key){
    return jQuery.i18n.prop(key);
}
```

This works fine if i keep a copy of the same property files i kept in my class path again in the folder where jsps are [ files may be like labels.properties, labels_en_US, and so on)

**Is there a way we can use a single copy of the property files kept in just one place?**

ie, if we kept it in the class path, it should be available over the url for the jquery plugin to use it ( ie, not just one file, it is picked up with different locales given to the 'language')

if we kept it in the web folder ( where the jsps are ), ResourseBundle.getBundle() should be able to pick it up from there.

I think we can use some code like :

```
String filePath  = getServletContext().getRealPath("Bundle/");
File file = new File(filePath);
URL[] urls = {file.toURI().toURL()};
ClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(urls);
ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("labels", Locale.getDefault(), loader);
```

... if the code is written in a servlet. But that's not always the case here.

It would be great if you could guide me in the right path. Probably I'm doing something wrong.